# Installing an editable python package inside a docker container

Tags: docker, django-allauth

I am trying to fix a bug in a python package for my project that runs inside a docker container.

The package I am talking about is [`django-allauth`](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and I found a small with one of the providers.

I know that I need to copy the edited package into the container and install it like this:

```
COPY folder/with/package /somefolder_inside_container/
RUN pip install -e /somefolder_inside_container/
```

The root folder of this project on github contains a lot of files and I am not sure if I should include them for copying to make sure the package installs. Do i need to copy anything besides the 'allauth' folder that contains all the models/views/etc. ?

Comment: You shouldn't need Docker at all for this.  Create a virtual environment and `pip install -e .` to get an editable installation of that package on your host system.